# Exibir dados de perfil do usuario logado

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

Bom galera to criando um painel onde tem a seção de meu perfil para o Administrador que estiver online pode ver as informações de seu perfil. Porém todavia contudo entretanto estou com problemas na criação da página de perfil, já li alguns tutorias e assisti algumas video-aulas, porém está tudo escuro ainda.

Eu queria saber como fazer para exibir em uma página as informações de um único usuário do banco de dados, sendo que no banco existem outros usuários também.

Eu sei selecionar tudo e exibir todos os usuários cadastrados no banco em uma página, mas eu queria mesmo era exibir as informações do usuário que estar logado, ou seja, só as dele.

eu utilizo um  pra redirecionar porem não faço ideia de como chamar um metodo que me retorne dos dados.

Comment: Se você já consegue selecionar todos os usuários cadastrados na base de dados, não consigo enxergar um motivo para não conseguir buscar um determinado usuário utilizando o login do mesmo como parâmetro da sua consulta

Comment: pois é!  a questão é que minha Named query que faço pra pegar o usuario não me retorna os dados

Comment: @NamedQuery(name="Usuario.findByid", 
query="select u from Usuario u "
  + "where u.login = :login")

Comment: DAO   `public Usuario buscarUsuairoPorLogin(String login) {
  EntityManager em = EntityManagerUtil.getEM();
  try{
   System.out.println("Login: " + login);
    return  (Usuario) em.createNamedQuery("Usuario.findByid")
       .setParameter("login", login)
       .getSingleResult();
   }catch (NoResultException nre){
   return null;
   }
 }`

Comment: bean `public String dadosUsuarioCadastrado() {
 UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO =  new UsuarioDAO();
 this.visualizaDadosUsuario = usuarioDAO.buscarUsuairoPorLogin(visualizaDadosUsuario.getLogin());
  return "/usuario/usuario_dadosCadastrais.xhtml";
 
}`

Comment: Inclui as suas classes na própria pergunta, assim fica mais fácil de alguém conseguir te auxiliar no problema em questão

Comment: conseguir resolver. Era apenas o eclipse que estava bugado. Bastou reiniciar-lo...vlw

Comment: Beleza, aproveita e edita sua pergunta, o correto é `Porém todavia contudo entretanto`